# играть в футбол

Tags: грамматика

1. Я играю в футбол и шахматы
2. Я играю в футбол и в шахматы

Is this sentences grammatically correct? 
Or we should use

3. Я играю в футбол и играю в шахматы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 and 2 are grammatically equal. I don't feel any of it unnatural. Though neither of these feels like a part of real conversation. I mean, the form is rather formal, but the subject is informal. "Играю в футбол, в шахматы ещё" might be a part of a real-world dialog.

3 is grammatically correct, but it is so formal that it should be avoided. Чуковский called this way of speaking sick and named the sickness "канцелярит" (officialese/bureaucratese).

Comment: Надежда, всё равно же 3 звучит так, будто говорит иностранец, разве нет? Несмотря на отсутствие грамматических ошибок

Comment: Некоторые наши люди тоже могут так говорить. Считают, что от этого кажутся умнее. Есть и ироничный вариант - Платонов именно в таком стиле писал.

Answer (score 4):

#3 sounds very-very unnatural. #2 is the best. #1 sounds a bit unnatural but still much better than #3. We don't like tautology :)